# Move all files in a folder to a new location if the same existing Folder name exists at remote location

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu

Looking for a bash script: 
Here's the situation:
I have 1000's folders and subfolders on my Backup Directory Drive
lets say.....

- /backup
- /backup/folderA
- /backup/folderA/FolderAA
- /backup/folderB
- /backup/folderB/FolderBB

I have Dozens of similar folders in a secondary location (with files in them) and the Folder names will match one of the folders or subfolders in the main backup drive.

I would like to move all contents of specific extension types from my secondary location $FolderName to the Backup location + matching subfolder ONLY if the $FolderName matches exactly and remove the folders from my secondary location!

If there is no corrosponding folder or subfolder in the backup location then leave the source folders & files alone.

looking forward to getting some help/guidance.

Mike

Additional info requested.Expected input and ouput

Lets say i have the following:
Backup Folder

```
/backup/test/file.bak
```

And for my secondary folder location:

```
/secondarylocation/mike/test/hello/john.bak
/secondarylocation/mike/test/hello/backup.zip
```

i would like this as the end result

```
/backup/test/file.bak
/backup/test/john.bak
/backup/test/backup.zip
```

and /secondarylocation/mike/test *and sub folders and files removed

Comment: Add the desired input and output.

Comment: Try `rsync` command

Comment: alecxs - as there was a folder called test in my secondary location & a folder called test also on my backuplocation then there is a match!!

Comment: you want *"move matching **sub**folder ONLY if the $FolderName matches"*, but you merged `hello` with `test`. Do you want to move files from **all** subfolders when just **parent** matches? And do you want to keep tree or only files of it? And do you want to overwrite files when duplicate file names exist in other subfolders?

Comment: alecxs - if Folder matches then I want to move all files of say .bak and .zip from the source location including all subfolders to the corrosponding folder on my backup location - I dont want to keep folder structure of secondary location - just movement of file. Mike.

Comment: @MikeSmith what would you want the script to do if you had 2 files with the same name?  lets say you had /secondarylocation/mike/test/hello/john.bak and /secondarylocation/mike/test/goodbye/john.bak what would you want to appear in /backup/test? Would you want to move them or not, and if you want to move do you want them renamed somehow?
Also, just to confirm, will /secondarylocation/mike/test/goodbye/charmander.bak and  /secondarylocation/mike/test/hello/squirtle.bak both end up in /backup/test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this script with quoted folders and file types:

```
./merge.sh "backup" "secondarylocation/mike" "*.zip" "*.bak"
```

- replace `-iname` with `-name` if you want to search for suffix case sensitive
- replace `mv -fv` with `mv -nv` when you don't want to overwrite duplicate file names
- add `-mindepth 1` to last `find` if you want to keep empty folder `test`

`merge.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# read folders from positional parameters
[ -d "$1" ] && targetf="$1" && shift
[ -d "$1" ] && sourcef="$1" && shift

if [ -z "$targetf" ] || [ -z "$sourcef" ]
  then
    echo -e "usage: ./merge.sh <targetfolder> <sourcefolder> [PATTERN]..."
    exit 1
fi

# add prefix -iname for each pattern
while [ ${pattern:-1} -le $# ]
  do
    set -- "$@" "-iname \"$1\""
    shift
    pattern=$((${pattern:-1}+1))
done

# concatenate all prefix+patterns with -o and wrap in parentheses ()
if (( $# > 1 ))
  then
    pattern="\( $1"
    while (( $# > 1 ))
      do
        pattern="$pattern -o $2"
        shift
    done
    pattern="$pattern \)"
  else
    pattern="$1"
fi

# move files from searchf to destf
find "$targetf" -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d $'\0' destf
  do
    find "$sourcef" -mindepth 1 -type d -name "${destf##*/}" -print0 | sort -z | while IFS=$'\0' read -r -d $'\0' searchf
      do
        if (( $# ))
          then
            # search with pattern
            eval find "\"$searchf\"" -depth -type f "$pattern" -exec mv -fv {} "\"$destf\"" \\\;
          else
            # all files
            find "$searchf" -depth -type f -exec mv -fv {} "$destf" \;
        fi
        # delete empty folders
        find "$searchf" -depth -type d -exec rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} +
    done
done

exit 0
```

this will merge `hello` into `test` (earn the fruits and cut the tree)

Comment: Fantastic - I will try this in a few hours and report back. Many thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay - Works Prefectly - I made a few adjustments base don my needs - But Fantastic work!!